# Can you explain to me this java code step by step?

Tags: java

This is a code, I don't understand

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = sum(10);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    public static int sum(int k) {
        if (k > 0) {
            return k + sum(k - 1);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The result is 55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recursive method.

As long as `k > 0`, the method will keep calling itself with a smaller value of `k`.

The initial call, `sum(10)` returns

```
 10 + sum(9) == 10 + 45 == 55
```

`sum(9)` returns

```
9 + sum(8) == 9 + 36 == 45
```

`sum(8)` returns

```
8 + sum(7) == 8 + 28 == 36
```

...

`sum(2)` returns

```
2 + sum(1) == 2 + 1 == 3
```

`sum(1)` returns

```
1 + sum(0) == 1 + 0 == 1
```

`sum(0)` returns 0.

Therefore the method returns the sum of all integers between 0 and 10, which is 55.